# Best way to thoroughly understand code in glibc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc, code-navigation

I am working on modifying glibc for my own purpose. However, it is very to difficult to relate difference pieces of code in different files of glibc as there is so much of it.

I want a functionality for example, such that when I see a function call, I can click it and be directed to that function, or for example, if I want to see where a function is defined I can be taken there, and more facilities like places where a function is used, opening header file by clicking it, caller-callee relationships and so on. Any tool can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

better use a IDE my suggestion is Eclipse CDT

Answer (score 0):

Most "programmers'" text editors and IDEs have a functionality similar to some of what you describe.  For example, both `vim` and `emacs` support `tags` files generated by the `ctags` command that list all of the function and variable definitions in a project.  In either editor, there is an appropriate key sequence that will take you directly to the definition for the term under your cursor.

Some of the other features you're looking for (like call graphs) can be generated by other external tools, or may be available in more feature-ful IDEs.